# generating sitemap with DOMDocument : missing AttributeNode in the output

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

im trying to generate a sitemap.xml , here is simplified version of my code

```
    $dom = new \DOMDocument();
    $dom->encoding = 'utf-8';
    $dom->xmlVersion = '1.0';
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    $xml_file_name = './sitemap.xml';
    $urlset = $dom->createElement('urlset');

    $attr_ = new \DOMAttr('xmlns:xsi', "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    $urlset->setAttributeNode($attr_);

    $url_node = $dom->createElement('url');

    $url_node_loc = $dom->createElement('loc',   'http://localhost' );
    $url_node->appendChild($url_node_loc);

    $url_node_lastmod = $dom->createElement('lastmod',  '2021-08-03T22:17:47+04:30' );
    $url_node->appendChild($url_node_lastmod);

    $urlset->appendChild($url_node);

    $dom->appendChild($urlset);
    $dom->save($xml_file_name);
    dd('done');
```

here is the output in my sitemap.xml

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<urlset>
    <url>
        <loc>http://localhost</loc>
        <lastmod>2021-08-03T22:17:47+04:30</lastmod>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

i need to add some attributes to my `urlset` tag , here is how i've did it

```
    $attr_ = new \DOMAttr('xmlns:xsi', "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    $urlset->setAttributeNode($attr_);
```

but for some reason this doesn't show up in my sitemap file , urlset has no attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setAttribute()` instead of `setAttributeNode()`.

```php
$urlset->setAttribute('xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not be a valid sitemap. Sitemaps use an XML namespace (https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html)

To create nodes with namespaces you should use the namespace aware DOM methods with the `*NS` suffix. This will add namespace definitions as needed.

`xmlns:xsi` is a namespace definition. They can be considered attributes nodes in the reserved namespace {http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/}.

```
$xmlns = [
  'sitemap' => 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9',
  'xmlns' => 'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/',  
  'xsi' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',  
];

$document = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$document->formatOutput = true;
    
$urlset = $document->appendChild(
    $document->createElementNS($xmlns['sitemap'], 'urlset')
);
// explict namespace definition
$urlset->setAttributeNS(
    $xmlns['xmlns'], 'xmlns:xsi', $xmlns['xsi']
);

$url_node = $urlset->appendChild(
  $document->createElementNS($xmlns['sitemap'], 'url')
);

$url_node
  ->appendChild($document->createElementNS($xmlns['sitemap'], 'loc'))
  ->textContent = 'http://localhost';
$url_node
  ->appendChild($document->createElementNS($xmlns['sitemap'], 'lastmod'))
  ->textContent = '2021-08-03T22:17:47+04:30';
  
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <url>
    <loc>http://localhost</loc>
    <lastmod>2021-08-03T22:17:47+04:30</lastmod>
  </url>
</urlset>
```